# С++ Мультисет Итератор

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

```
auto greater = [](unsigned u1, unsigned u2) {return u1 > u2;};
multiset<Class>::iterator it = multiset.begin();
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
   cout << *it++ << endl;
}
```

Нужно вывести первые 3 элемента, но согласно моей лямбда-сортировке

Comment: если функтор сравнения отличается от того на котором построено дерево, то быстрого способа нет — только обход всех элементов `multiset`'а и поиск минимальных. Какие-нить красивости stl'я на вскидку для этого не придумаю, но общий алгоритм строчек в 10 уложится...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Напишите, пожалуйста, Эти 10 строчек))

Comment: лямбда_сортировка?  Только можно догадаться о чем речь

Comment: В вопросе написана какая-то полнейшая бессмыслица. Какое отношение ваша лямбда, принимающая `unsigned` параметры, имеет к мультисету, хранящему некий `Class`??? Что за  `Class`? К чему он тут? Потрудитесь осмысленно сформулировать вопрос. На текущий момент ни о каком ответе речи быть не может.

Answer (score 0):

Немного больше получилось т.к. оформил в виде шаблона в стиле stl, который возвращает `N` максимальных элементов для заданного диапазона итераторов с заданным компаратором:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

#include <assert.h>

template<class InputIt, class LessPredicate>
std::multiset < typename InputIt::value_type, LessPredicate >
max_elements (InputIt begin, InputIt end, size_t N, LessPredicate pred) {

  assert (N>0);

  std::multiset < typename InputIt::value_type, LessPredicate> rv(pred);

  auto it = begin;
  for (size_t i = 0; i<N && it != end; i++, it++) {
    rv.insert (*it);
  }

  for (; it != end; it++) {
    if (pred (*rv.begin(), *it)) {
      rv.erase (rv.begin());
      rv.insert (*it);
    }
  }

  return rv;
}

int main () {
  auto less = [](int u1, int u2)-> bool {return u1 < u2;};

  std::vector<int> vec = {1,0,8,12,2,3,5,5,8};
  int N = 3;

  std::cout << N << " maximum elements are: ";
  for(int el : max_elements (vec.begin(), vec.end(), N, less) ){
     std::cout << el << ' ';
  }

  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Я не большой мастак писать шаблоны и, вероятно код отлажен недостаточно усердно, так что замечания приветствуются;

Также вероятно, если заменить дерево на кучу, то выйдет несколько оптимальней.

Answer (score 0):

Может неправильно сформулировал, но вот правильный ответ,
всем спасибо)

```
auto greater = [](unsigned u1, unsigned u2) {return u1 > u2;};
multiset<Class,decltype(greater)> myMultiset(greater);
int i=1;

for(const auto& it:myMultiset){
  cout << it << endl;
  if(i > 3) break;
}
```